How to change rootViewController from UIInputWindowController to UINavigationController
there
The CardinalMobile SDK presents the OTP screen, after the OTP screen is dismissed I cannot show loading from SVProgressHUD.
I have checked rootViewController, it's changed from UINavigationController to UIInputWindowController. 
Could anyone here help with this?
I spent almost a week trying to fix it.


First you need to understand why it's switching your rootView. How are you presenting the SDK?

The CardinalMobile sdk presenting OTP view by itself.
Here is code.
CardinalSession().continueWith(transactionId: transactionID, payload: payload, validationDelegate: self)

I remember that SVProgressHUD will show HUD on the topmost controller by default. How did you present the HUD in this scenario?

This is how i show SVProgressHUD "SVProgressHUD.show()"
I print rootViewController before and after SDK presenting OTP screen.
before OTP screen: rootViewController is UINavigationController
after OTP screen: rootViewController is UIInputWindowController

I am assuming the flow is: UINavigationController -> CCVIewController -> focus on OTP field -> present keyboard -> show HUD, right? If this is the case, I think you should handle HUD on callback or delegate from this SDK.

Not sure how this SDK works, but it changing your rootView is 100% the issue. Anyway you can create the OTP screen wrap in a NavController and present it?

Manipulating the rootViewController can lead to unpredictable behaviour.
Assuming the SVProgressHUD does not find the correct window automatically, you can manually specify the container view.
DispatchQueue.main.async {
if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter({ $0.isKeyWindow }).first {
    SVProgressHUD.setContainerView(keyWindow)
    SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Loading...")
}

}
For iOS 13 and above:
DispatchQueue.main.async {
if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene {
    if let keyWindow = windowScene.windows.filter({ $0.isKeyWindow }).first {
        SVProgressHUD.setContainerView(keyWindow)
        SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Loading...")
    }
}

}
